# Limit problem involving cosine

Tags: calculus, limits

Simply, how would you calculate $$\lim_{x \to 0}x^3\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

I gave this problem by accident to my calculus 1 class.

Comment: What can you say about $\cos \frac{1}{x}$ without looking at $x$?

Comment: Always between 1 and -1

Comment: The rest is squeezy-peasy, isn't it?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahah, good one.

Comment: Do it out fully

Comment: @MatthewLevy Do you know that $\lim \limits_{x\to a}(|f(x)|)=0\implies \lim \limits_{x\to a}f(x)=0$?

Comment: $-|x|^3\le x^3\cos(\text{anything real})\le|x|^3$. Seriously.

Comment: I just thought it was a little unfair to first year calculus students... idk. They just learned the Squeeze Theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remeber that $ -1 < \cos(t) < 1$. Thus, by the comparison rule,

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}{-|x|^3} \leq \lim_{x \to 0}x^3\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)  \leq \lim_{x \to 0}{|x|^3}.
$$

Applying the limits,

$$
0 \leq \lim_{x \to 0}x^3\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)  \leq 0.
$$

Therefore,

$$
\lim_{x \to 0}x^3\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 0.
$$